# How can i move all elements in an Array then remove 1 element and keep the movement going

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to simulate a deck of cards beeing spread. I have 10 card elements in an Array and i can loop through them with

```
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
     cardArray[i].style.left = 20 + pos + "px";
}
```

I increment the `pos++` and when i get to `pos == 30` i want to `splice()` one of the elements (1 card), so it will stop and continue moving the rest of the array with 9 elements left in it and i can't figure out how to do that repeatedly. I can only move all elements `30px` them remove 1 element from the array and everything stops there. I use `setInterval` to make it look like animated.

```js
var cardOne = document.querySelector("#card1");
var cardTwo = document.querySelector("#card2");
var cardThree = document.querySelector("#card3");
var Btn = document.querySelector("#startBtn");
var topCard = document.querySelector("#topCard");

Btn.addEventListener("click", cards);

var cardArray = [cardOne, cardTwo, cardThree];
console.log(cardArray);

function myMove() {
  topCard.style.display = "none";
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  var pos = 0;
  var k = 0;
  var l = cardArray.length;
  console.log(cardArray);

  function frame() {
    k++
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      cardArray[i].style.left = 20 + pos + k + "px";
      console.log(cardArray);
    }
    if (k == 30) {
      clearInterval(id);
      pos += k;
      cardArray.splice(0, 1);
      // console.log(pos);
      // console.log(k);
      // console.log(cardArray);
    }
  }
}


function cards() {
  document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = "Choose a random card";
  document.getElementById("start-container").style.margin = "50px 0 0 0";
  document.getElementById("intro").style.height = "50px";
  document.getElementById("intro").style.margin = "0 0 0 220px";
  document.getElementById("wrapper").style.display = "flex";
}
```

Comment: can you attach a snippet or post some more code its difficult to understand

Comment: you want you 10 `card` elms to be in row at distance of `20px`?

Comment: Looks like the problem is that you are changing the size of the array while iterating over it, but definitely it would help to see more code to understand it better.

Comment: Guys i'm new to the forum i don't know how to post code here. Maheer Ali that is what i want and i want it to look smooth moving 1px at a time. Please tell me how to post more code because it says the comment is too long.

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Instead click "edit" on the question, and either use the snippet tool (the button with the `<>` on it) to make it runnable inside the question,  or the code sample button (marked with `{}`) to just make it visible as code.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will know it for next time

Comment: I don't think you actually want to remove it from the array - just not set its position to anything larger than 30.

Comment: how can i do that while still looping through the other elements to change their position 1px at a time?

Comment: you want to move cards in certain amount of time away from each other and then stop when they are at specific distance from each other?

Comment: i want to move all the cards and leave 1 card behind to make it look like you spread cards on a table. So i want the whole array to move as a stack and at 30px or some other set distance one card stops and the rest keep moving. So far I'm testing with 3 cards in an array and i can move them to the first "checkpoint" and remove 1 card from the Array but the rest of them need to keep moving to the next "checkpoint" whitch needs to be at the same distance every time until there are no cards in the Array left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand what you want, the problem seems to be that you clear the interval timer after the first 30 calls to "frame()"

```
clearInterval(id);
```

Maybe, you could do it like the following:

```
if (k == 30) {
  pos += k;
  cardArray.splice(0, 1);
  if (cardArray.length===0) clearInterval(id);
  k=0; // i think, you need to reset the counter here, right?
}
```

You also initialize your l variable to the cardArray's length, then later shorten the array but do not update the loop's upper bound. so, the line

```
var l = cardArray.length;
```

should go from the outer function into the `frame()` method, before the for loop.

Comment: Yes you understand perfectly. The problem is that after the first card stopps the rest never stop and the Console gives error

 "script.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at frame".

Also i changed splice to pop() so that the last element is removed but i think thats not so important. I want to figure out how to stop the other cards from moving forever.

Comment: Oh, i missed that: you need to update your `l`variable at the beginning of the `frame()`method - will update the answer

Comment: Well actually i made it work with forEach to avoid the l variable. 
cardArray.forEach( function move(item) {
          let i = cardArray.indexOf(item);
          cardArray[i].style.left = 20 + pos + k + "px";
        });    This made it work like a charm. Thanks for the help with the interval. Very helpfull. Cheers

Comment: In your forEach, what you make the computer do is: "Find me the place where item is in the list and then update the style of the item at that place in the list" (i hope, you understand what i try to say :-) ) - you can just use `item` directly like this: `cardArray.forEach( function (item) {  item.style.left = 20 + pos + k + "px"; });`. You also do not need to name the function (i left out the name `move`).

Comment: You are absolutely right. Didn't stop to think about it. Thank you so much.